# Trying to install new wifi router, continually losing its gateway, sometimes crashing entire network

Tags: dhcp, wifi

So, I'm trying to set up a buffalo router with dd-wrt loaded stock, If I leave the settings alone, the router loses its default gateway each time, and the router admin back-end is never accessible again. 
I've tried disabling DHCP, no wan, making it a DHCP forwarder, and giving it a static IP that is free.
We already have a DHCP server running which I think is conflicting. 
One time I gave it a static IP and it seemed to crash all of our network, including phones, momentarily.

The router is a Buffalo WZR-HP-AG300H, with ddwrt, network has DHCP server running that I can't take out of equation, various firewalls, etc.

Any suggestions on purely making this an access point that doesn't lose its gateway?

Comment: If you just need a wireless access point why are you using a wireless router? I'm not saying that you can't use it as a wireless access point but it's going to make things more complicated then they need to be.

Answer (score 2):

Disable the router's DHCP server. Do not connect the router's WAN port to anything (unless you know how to configure DD-WRT to make it another LAN port). It doesn't matter if the router has a default gateway or not. Assign the router's LAN side an IP address that is inside your subnet but outside the range of DHCP addresses assigned by the existing router. Connect one of the router's LAN ports to one of the existing router's LAN ports.

Don't keep trying random configurations. You'll blow through the correct ones without even noticing. Set things up precisely the way you want them and then, if it doesn't work, troubleshoot carefully.